# How to resolve a CS8602(Dereference of a possibly null reference) when redirecting on null?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have the following code:

```
    GetBenefitById_Result? objBenefit = _db.GetBenefitById(this.BenefitId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (objBenefit == null)
        Response.Redirect(URLConstants.BENEFIT_LIST);

    lblName.Text = objBenefit.Name; //This gives me the error CS8602.
```

When I build this code, I get the warning "Dereference of a possibly null reference". I know that what is happening is that the compiler is trying to protect me from trying to access the variable Name if objBenefit is null, but how do I tell the compiler that I am redirecting on null, so don't check this?

Comment: Shouldn’t you have a `return` after `Response.Redirect`?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
   if (objBenefit == null) {
        Response.Redirect(URLConstants.BENEFIT_LIST);
   }
   else
   {
      lblName.Text = objBenefit.Name;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value won't be null, you can use the null-forgiving operator (!):

```
if (objBenefit == null)
        Response.Redirect(URLConstants.BENEFIT_LIST);

    lblName.Text = objBenefit!.Name;
```

Comment: They do not know the value won't be null though, if they knew that, they wouldn't be doing a null check two lines above.

Comment: @Perusion - er, what?

Comment: Right. They do a null check and now they know it's not null. They can now tell the compiler that they know it can't be null with the null-forgiving operator.

Comment: But control flows to the .ast statement even in the null case.